# How to set user-agent in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I tried this, but I get an error.

```
http.get({ url: 'http://www.panda.tv/ajax_chatinfo?roomid=89757',
    agent: 'Mozilla/5.0' }, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        doSomething();
    });
});
```

I read the API documentation, but I didn't find anything on how to create.

When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
_http_client.js:158
    self.agent.addRequest(self, options);
               ^

TypeError: self.agent.addRequest is not a function
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:158:16)
    at Object.exports.request (http.js:31:10)

    at Object.exports.get (http.js:35:21)
    at getChatInfo (/home/zeek/Documents/pandatv/node/app.js:5:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/zeek/Documents/pandatv/node/app.js:153:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
```

Comment: property `agent` you set is not the `user-agent` read the docs

Comment: The docs for the HTTP module https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback show that `agent` is something different. The `user-agent` is an HTTP header, so you need to set it in the `headers` instead.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
const options = {
  hostname: 'www.panda.tv',
  path: 'ajax_chatinfo?roomid=89757',
  headers: { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0' }
};

http.get(options, function(res) {
  res.on('data', function(chunk) { console.log(chunk) });
});
```

Consider next npm modules [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) or [superagent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent), they will help you much with processing http requests. Drop a comment if you need examples, but I'm sure you'll get it from documentations. GL.

Comment: `
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1008:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1031:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1080:14)`

Comment: I copied your params, but there is not `url` param. I did update the answer. Let me know if it ok.

Comment: run the url in browser get a json.

Comment: @user3130007, I know, but this is the way `http` works, it works with raw binary data, if you need json you have to get full binstring and convert it to utf. But there are less complex way, I'm going to update my answer in a minute.

Comment: Thans a lot for your help! :)

Comment: The path must be started with slash. path: '/ajax_chatinfo?roomid=89757'.