# Setting mobile user agent for iframe on desktop

Tags: javascript, php, http, iframe, user-agent

I am attempting to use an iframe to preview the mobile version for a site that will be displayed on the desktop site. However the site that I am attempting to display does not use the screen size to activate the mobile version but rather a user agent. Will I be able to somehow make the iframe request the site based of a mobile user agent such as 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.2; en-us; Galaxy Nexus Build/ICL53F) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30'?

Comment: A bullet-proof cross-browser solution would be to take a screen-shot of a mobile page, and delivere it as an image.

Comment: @Teemu — Try that when the user depends on a screen reader, or wants to click a link on the embedded page.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is marked with both Javascript and PHP tags, two quite different languages, one client-side, the other server-side, respectively. Changing the UserAgent string cannot be done with Javascript. It could be done with a HTTP header set by PHP running on a proxy server between your browser and the site that will load in the iFrame.

On the other hand, if you use node.js server-side, you may be able to set the userAgent header with Javascript (a [related OS Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788873/how-to-set-user-agent-in-nodejs) may help).