# Receiving different response headers when accessing site through browser vs node http module

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, http, http-headers

I'm writing a function in my node server that detects whether a particular URL can be rendered inside an i-frame by checking the `x-frame-options` field in the header.

While this works correctly, for some sites I am receiving a header without this field when accessed through the http module. However the header for these sites correctly includes this option when opened in the browser.

For example: when accessing **artstation.com**:

In **Node.js** the Response headers are:

```
{"date":"Fri, 17 Jan 2020 03:37:06 GMT",
"connection":"close","cache-control":"private, 
max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, 
post-check=0, pre-check=0","expires":"Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT",
"location":"https://www.artstation.com/",
"x-content-type-options":"nosniff",
"server":"cloudflare",
"cf-ray":"556549e5fbeaefd8-EWR"}
```

In **Chrome browser** the response headers are:

```
cache-control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
cf-ray: 5565511b5d3fe6d0-EWR
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Fri, 17 Jan 2020 03:42:01 GMT
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
server: cloudflare
set-cookie: _ArtStation_session=TEFNMnlrR0UrK1A0UTgzM2FqOGJhMXZkU2dhYitxVW83ajJhMXo0SzJ4T0tENGhwYVppVTZpL0lOSHZ1M0pmRERRaUZ5Z0FTMWRuWTRsTm95VHQwUlhlcEdXN1JCSGtsL0pPdHNtSFF4R3ZScjhUOHFDOWkrSEg3RjNoemZ5aFVWMGJweXFwQU56Q3dOV25icXNNNGtjK3RwbDB4Tml0cjZWSHRWZ1dMK0FSajl2OHZoazFrckVaSTcyRkxFRHAzbHQrbTlpUnZudmRoVXNKYkF5TmlyUT09LS1rVkhhWG5OZ3ZOK0hUckdhY0pRbDJ3PT0%3D--083e61c9e5af420688bc4d309212aafb2de70ebb; domain=.artstation.com; path=/; expires=Fri, 17 Jan 2020 05:12:01 -0000; secure; HttpOnly
status: 200
status: 200 OK
strict-transport-security: max-age=0
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-powered-by: Phusion Passenger Enterprise
x-request-id: 1e36371b-eb7c-419e-97ae-6c9ac901c240
x-runtime: 0.040934
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

As you can see the `x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN` is present in the response headers in Chrome but *not* in Node.

Why are the response headers different?

Also, please note that this behaviour does not apply to all sites. When accessing google.com, the headers match in the browser and node.

Comment: It may be returning different data based on the user agent in the request. You could try passing the Chrome UA as part of your node request and see what you get back

Comment: It might be because the website is using cloudflare which is having some rules to block access to website without having certain headers / browsers. Try faking your node code as Googlebot or a browser as user agent and see what happens see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788873/how-to-set-user-agent-in-nodejs

Comment: Thanks! tried passing Chrome/googlebot/mozilla in the request but no luck. Response is still the same